# Error code: Runtime exception at 0x00400010: address out of range 0x00000000

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

.data
prompt1: .asciiz "This program reads in a String from the user and then allows the user to make changes to it until they want to stop.\n"
prompt2: .asciiz "Please enter your string now (maximum of 40 characters):\n"
prompt3: .asciiz "Your current string is:\n"
prompt4: .asciiz "Do you want to make any changes to the string? (Y/N): "
prompt5: .asciiz "Enter the character in the string you would like replaced: "
prompt6: .asciiz "Enter what you would like to change the character to: "
prompt7: .asciiz "Your final string is:\n"

.text
.globl main

swap_characters:
addi $sp, $sp, -8
sw $ra, 4($sp)
sw $s0, 0($sp)

```
move $s0, $a0
```

loop:
lb $t0, 0($s0)
beqz $t0, done
beq $t0, $a1, replace

```
addiu $s0, $s0, 1  
j loop
```

replace:
sb $a2, 0($s0)
addiu $s0, $s0, 1
j loop

done:
lw $ra, 4($sp)
lw $s0, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8
jr $ra

main:

```
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt1
syscall


li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall


li $v0, 8
la $a0, 0($v1)      
li $a1, 40         
syscall


li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt3
syscall


li $v0, 4
la $a0, 0($v1)      
syscall
```

change_loop:
# Prompt for making changes
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt4
syscall

```
li $v0, 12
syscall


beqz $v0, done1      


li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt5
syscall


li $v0, 12
syscall


move $a1, $v0


li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt6
syscall


li $v0, 12
syscall


move $a2, $v0


move $a0, $v1      
jal swap_characters


li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt3
syscall

# Print the updated string
li $v0, 4
la $a0, 0($v1)      
syscall

j change_loop
```

done1:

```
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt7
syscall


li $v0, 4
la $a0, 0($v1)      


li $v0, 10
syscall
```

I thought I had the program done correctly and it won't run. What did I do wrong. This is an assignment for class. It is happening on the line lb $t0, 0($s0) in the loop. Can anyone help?

Comment: Find out what line of preceeding code put 0 in s0.

Comment: Try running the debugger -- single step it.  Does `main` run at all?  Do you have the "use `main`" option set?

Comment: Move `swap_characters` underneath `main` and try it again. I think what's happening is that your `swap_characters` function is running first, as it's the first thing you wrote. Which would explain why `$s0` is still zero when you enter it.